# Issue with columns in csv using pandas groupby

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, pandas-groupby

I have these below columns in my csv . Usually all these columns have value like below and the code works smoothly .

```
dec list_namme  list    device        Service    Gate
12   food      cookie   200.56.57.58    Shop     123
```

Now I encountered issue, I got one csv file that has all these columns but there is no content for them. Here it looks like..

```
dec list_namme  list    device  Service Gate
```

and once the code runs over it , it creates new csv with below columns that was not expected. I got new columns name as **index** and also , instead of 3(`device service Gate`) columns I am getting wrong 2.

```
index   Gate
```

For the csv having contents I didnot faced any issue , even the columns are coming correctly.

Below is the code.
The code is :

```
if os.path.isfile(client_csv_file):
         df=pd.read_csv(csv_file) #Read CSV
         df['Gate']=df.Gate.astype(str)
         df = df.groupby(['device', 'Service'])['Gate'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(set(x))).reset_index()
     df.to_csv(client_out_file, index=False)
```

Please help me in this code to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performing a `groupby` on an empty dataframe is resulting in a dataframe without groupby-key columns.

One solution is to test if your dataframe is empty before performing manipulations:

```
if os.path.isfile(client_csv_file):
    df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
    if df.empty:
        df = df[['device', 'Service', 'Gate']]
    else:
        df['Gate'] = df.Gate.astype(str)
        df = df.groupby(['device', 'Service'])['Gate']\
               .apply(lambda x: ', '.join(set(x))).reset_index()
    df.to_csv(client_out_file, index=False)
```

Comment: This seems to be good idea . Will try in some time and will update you .